# drawing canvas works as long i use it one time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing a canvas and rotating it based on a value, it works if i use the canvas one time on a page.

If i add it the second time to the page, only the last one gets drawn, i cant find the error in my code and i dont get a js error.

i think the problem is in the next function:

```
function animate(){ 

function drawnumbers()
{context.save(); 
context.fillStyle = "#000000"; 
context.translate(73,0); 
context.font="10px Orbitron"; 
context.textAlign = "center"; 
context.rotate(((i*(180/min)))*Math.PI/180); 
context.fillText(data.values[i].amount,0,3); 
context.restore(); 
}; 
if (d < defer){ 
context.clearRect(0,0,400,400); 
d++; 

context.save(); 
var ang = ((((d-minn)*(180/angle)))*(Math.PI/180)); 
context.translate(38,39); 
context.scale(.8,.8); 
base_image = new Image(); 

base_image.src = 'http://oi44.tinypic.com/2hfkx8p.jpg'; 
context.translate(base_image.width/2, base_image.height/2); 
context.rotate(ang ); 
context.drawImage(base_image, -base_image.width/2, -base_image.height/2); 
context.restore(); 

context.save();
context.beginPath(); 
context.arc(100,100,64,1*Math.PI,2*Math.PI, false); 
context.lineWidth = .4; 
context.strokeStyle="#00A1DE"; 
context.globalAlpha = 0.7; 
context.stroke(); 
context.restore(); 

context.save(); 
context.translate(100,100); 
context.rotate(Math.PI/180); 
context.strokeStyle = "#00A1DE"; 
context.lineWidth = .7; 
for (var i=0;i < data.values.length; i++){ 
context.beginPath(); 
context.moveTo(62,0); 
context.lineTo(67,0); 
context.stroke(); 
context.globalAlpha = 0.7; 
drawnumbers(); 
context.rotate((182/(min))*(-Math.PI/180)); 
} 
context.restore(); 

context.fillStyle="white"; 
context.fillRect(38,101,123,75); 

context.save(); 
context.fillStyle = "#00a1de"; 
context.font = "22px Orbitron"; 
context.textAlign = "center"; 
context.fillText(defer, 100, 90); 
context.restore(); 

context.save(); 
context.fillStyle = "#000000"; 
context.font = "10px arial"; 
context.textAlign = "center"; 
context.fillText(eenheid, 100, 115); 
context.restore(); 

} 
else 
{ 
clearTimeout(t); 
}; 
t=setTimeout("animate()",30-d); 
};
```

check example to better understand:

```
http://jsbin.com/ogEgURu/1/
```

I had it in a function but it remains the same problem so i think something is wrong with my code.

Can anyone see the problem i am not seeing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is way too complex, especially since there is no good reason for this complexity.
Copying a big (>200) lines block of code to duplicate a functionality is error-prone.
You'll be able to see easily the issue once you refactored your code.
Just a few hints :

- Very easy one : beautify the code.
- No redundancy : If a code lies here twice or more, make a function and factorize.
- Break down the code into smaller parts. For example :  drawText(context, text, x,y, font ) (to print eenheid and defer), drawNumbers(context), drawRotatingImage(context, angle), ...
- use closePath() each time you beginPath();
- load once the image when page loads, and wait for it to be loaded before animating.
- do not define a function in a loop (drawnumbers).
- use a single object to store the several parameters (context, angle, ...), or
  even switch to an object oriented style.
- have only *one* animate() loop, that will call several draw(...) functions if need be.

after all this, your code will look much simpler, and the bug should vanish very quickly.

I did this work (partially), in this fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/ztczK/1/    (edited)

The code looks like :

```
// parameters : settings for one gauge display
var parameters1 = {
    data: data,
    defer: '520',
    context: context,
    left: 38,
    top: 30,
    d: 0,
    angle: 0,
    scale: 0.8,
    //... whatever parameter here
};
var parameters2 = ... ;
```

split the draw into many functions so it's much simpler to understand :

```
// draws a gauge
function drawGauge(param) {
    preDraw(param);
    drawBaseImage(param);
    drawArc(param);
    drawTheNumbers(param);
    writeDefer(param);
    writeEenheid(param);
    postDraw(param);
}

// translate and scales context, and updates some values for the gauge
function preDraw(param) {
    var minn = param.data.values[param.data.values.length - 1].amount;
    var maxn = data.values[0].amount;
    var angle = maxn - minn;
    var d = param.d;
    param.ang = ((((d - minn) * (180 / angle))) * (Math.PI / 180));
    var ctx = param.context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(param.left, param.top);
    ctx.scale(param.scale, param.scale);
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 60, 123, 75);
}

// restore context
function postDraw(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    ctx.restore();
    param.d++;
}

function drawBaseImage(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    var ang = param.ang;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(base_image.width / 2, base_image.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.drawImage(base_image, -base_image.width / 2, -base_image.height / 2);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawArc(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(base_image.width / 2, base_image.height / 2, 64, 1 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = .4;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00A1DE";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 10.7;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}

function writeDefer(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    var defer = param.defer;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00a1de";
    ctx.font = "22px Orbitron";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(defer, base_image.width / 2, base_image.height / 2);
    ctx.restore();
}

function writeEenheid(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "10px arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(eenheid, base_image.width / 2, base_image.height / 2 + 20);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawTheNumbers(param) {
    var ctx = param.context;
    var dataValues = param.data.values;
    var count = dataValues.length;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(base_image.width / 2, base_image.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#00A1DE";
    ctx.lineWidth = .7;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "10px Orbitron";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(62, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(67, 0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillText(dataValues[i].amount, 60, 3);
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / count);
    }
    context.restore();
}
```

then animate becomes very simple, even with several gauges :

```
function animate() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    drawGauge(parameters1);
    drawGauge(parameters2);
    setTimeout(animate, 15);
};
base_image.onload = animate();
```

Comment: did you get it to work in the bin ? i tried it for 2 days but everytime different errors like if the function is not defined and so one

Comment: no, i did not touch the bin. I just had a look, and i suggested a new way of organizing the code. Anyone can change a jsbin unless locked, so be sure to lock it before publishing it, or use jsfiddle (which has an 'update' button)

Comment: i am a beginner and i understand half what you are saying you do everything in different functions. but cant you show me how you would do it because i got the theory but i cant figure out how to do it so this is my version of it... i got it this far : http://jsbin.com/AwOBATAY/5/edit but that still doesnt work

Comment: thanks m8 i understand where you are going! i am going to try to change the function so i can let it work like i wanted it to.. (half and dont circle all day :P)

Comment: you're welcome. +1 and/or accept if it's useful. In fact the 'best' way to do this is to use classes, so each gauge object has its own set of properties and the syntax becomes clearer (gauge1.draw()). But i did not use class not knowing if you're easy with that.

Comment: I tried to fix it so that it will resemble how i want to use it with the same functions you are using but i cant get it done. the way i had in mind to work does not work anymore. any idea how to get the results as in http://jsbin.com/AwOBATAY/6

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46157/discussion-between-michaelangelo-and-gamealchemist)